# Wordpress - Own plugin - get all images of the media gallery

Tags: wordpress

i've written a plugin for the Wordpress TinyMCE editor and i want to use images which have been previously uploaded to the media gallery in that plugin. How can i access all uploaded pictures in my own plugin? I can't find it in the wordpress docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly not clear on your question.  Are you looking for a method to access the Add Media button?

In attempts to answer your question -> This method allows you to get all attachments that is in your media section..  Currently it displays everything but you can manipulate it the way you want to.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
```